# HTML 5 iOS facebook javascript SDK fullscreen home screen app issue

Tags: ios, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to put a html5 app on the home screen on iOS device, but seems that in safari it open a new tab and then closes when login its success, in the home screen app seems that it open a new window and when login its complete I only get a blank screen.

My question its there is a way to build a fullscreen iOS html app with facebook javascript SDK?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was [here](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/11/23/facebook-javascript-sdk-redirect-to-request-for-permissions-page-if-the-user-is-not-logged-in-or-not-subscribed/). You must specify the redirect uri, where the app should go after the user login on facebook.